# Word2Vec word embeddings on H2O Deep Water with GPU

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec, h2o, grid-search, gbm

We followed the text categorization process with iterating the items below:

1. Create a Word2Vec word embedding model with text documents.
2. Do a Grid Search and tree depth parameters.
3. Select the best performed Final GBM model.

As we iterate through the list CPU cores are working at %100 load. Are there any procedure or solution iterating the above process with H2O Deep Water GPU capabilities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no and maybe.

The maybe is that you could switch from GBM to xgboost, which does have a GPU option (I believe only single-node is supported, and only in Linux currently). xgboost is apparently slightly quicker on small data sets, h2o.gbm slightly quicker on large data sets. If you have a GPU going free, and are using the latest version of H2O, it should be easy to swap `h2o.gbm` with `h2o.xgboost` (`H2OXGBoostEstimator` if using Python API) and see for yourself.

I'd be interested to hear the relative timings!

(BTW, the 2nd "no" is for GPU use specifically for grids; but all the effort is in the models, not the grid itself, so the 2nd "no" could just as well be "N/A")

Comment: When we use H2OXGBoostEstimator instead of GBM, it seems to have better performance but the implementation suffers from finishing the grid search. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/45726324/1928229)